# My computer runs slower now on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, performance, macbook, minecraft

Recently I have been noticing that my laptop's speed has decreased after installing Ubuntu.  I am on a MacBook Pro and I have 4.2GHz and 4GB of RAM. I used to play games like Minecraft before on it and they ran fine with 60 FPS. But now that I am in Ubuntu, things don't go as fast as they used to.

I made Minecraft run with 3GB of RAM and I installed Optifine, but it is still slow! I don't know what to do anymore!

Comment: Are you comparing same versions of minecraft? The recent 1.5.2 has me at 50fps and the 1.4.7 version had it at 120fps, so minecraft has slowed it fps (frames per second)

Comment: No im not.  I was running 1.5.2 when I swapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing cpu indicator it allows you to change the speed of your CPU

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Then logout and login again and you will see a little cpu indicator in your notification panel. Set it to "Permormance" and that should boost the speed.

Answer (score 2):

For a bit more info, open a terminal and type 'top'. It will show you what's running and what's at the top is likely your problem.